Kubernetes ingress throws 502 under Jmeter load of 50/m with 30s response delay injected
I have a java web application that runs on Tomcat as a container that is hosted on Rancher. With a load of 50 http soap calls per min the applications works good with no fallouts, and each request takes about 2-4 seconds to complete.
When I rerun the test and introduce 30s response delay (via chaos testing tools) into the mix, some of the calls triggered via JMeter fallout with 502 right away, some after 60 seconds and some much later. I see about 20 calls in total out of 400 that get dropped with 502. I reviewed the pod (2 pods) metrics and the CPU and memory usage but they are well below 50%.
I tried setting ingress timeout but that did not help either.
My ingress timeout config looks as below,
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 10m
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream: error timeout http_502 non-idempotent
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: '650'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: '3'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: JSESSIONID
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'false'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'

Much appreciated if I am pointed in the right direction to understand what could be the problem and what else I can try to resolve the issue.
###########################
Update: Noticed below error message on the ingress side.
[error] 260453#260453: *389426939 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.22.33.44, server: abc.def.intranet, request: "POST /hello/0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://11.22.33.44:9023/hello/0", host: "abc.def.intranett"


Where is the delay being injected (on the server or the client side; at what point in the HTTP request flow)?  If a request takes 2-4s to execute then a single replica can only handle 15-30 requests/min, and it may not necessarily be CPU- or memory-bound.  Do you actually have enough capacity in your system to handle these requests?

The delay is injected at server side, on the tool it says a delay of 30s is injected for response. There are 2 pods behind the service that ingress talks to so load is distributed between them.

Are the requests serial or parallel?  Does the delay block a thread?  Is it possible the delay blocks Kubernetes health checks?  If individual requests are taking 30+ seconds to complete then some HTTP timeouts and similar 5xx errors from proxies are probably expected.

The requests are trigger parallel with 20 threads. You do bring up a good point, that whether the health check also gets delayed and the ingress considers the pod not being ready yet intermittently and throws 502. I looked at my ingress config but there are no healthcheck rules defined, wondering where that could be.  I tested both request delay and response delay and they both result in same behaviour, however I noticed that even though response delay is set to 30s, the requests which are processed arent displaying that it took 30+ s to complete, they still show 2-5s which is weird.

@DavidMaze: An update, tested the (2)pods behind the service with GET request and they do not throw 502 gateway error, this error is occurring only for POST requests and I am unsure why, the GET and POST methods have same functionality within it (a print statement).  So this eliminates pod healthy check being the issue since GET seem to work.

Another update: found below log from the ingress [error] 260453#260453: *389426939 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.22.33.44, server: abc.def.intranet, request: "POST /hello/0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "11.22.33.44:9023/hello/0", host: "abc.def.intranett"
